# What does the Kibana ML Categorization Mean/Used For

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I understand that the ML Categorization in Kibana is used for log/machine generated data. But I'm a bit confused about what it actually produces and its use case.

Is it safe to say that it is used to group categories of similar messages and that the results are where a record differs from the group? Please explain!